# Merge text files by a common column and save as csv file

Tags: r, csv, merge, tidyverse, txt

I have hundred's of data files in the (*.txt format) containing column A as "Gene IDs" and column B as "counts". I would like to merge all the files by "Gene IDs" into one *.csv file format and name the subsequent counts columns (column B, C D, etc) by corresponding *.txt file names in the *.csv file. Please assist me with this.

**Example of the input file(s) in the *.txt format:**

*Sample_File_1*

```
dput(head(Sample_File_1))
structure(list(`Gene IDs` = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000005", 
"ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938"
), Sample_File_1.counts = c(0L, 0L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 242L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Sample_File_2*

```
dput(head(Sample_File_2))
structure(list(`Gene IDs` = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000005", 
"ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938"
), Sample_File_2.counts = c(0L, 0L, 18L, 21L, 3L, 413L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Sample_File_3*

```
dput(head(Sample_File_3))
structure(list(`Gene IDs` = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000005", 
"ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938"
), Sample_File_3.counts = c(0L, 0L, 24L, 13L, 2L, 400L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Sample_File_4*

```
dput(head(Sample_File_4))
structure(list(`Gene IDs` = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000005", 
"ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938"
), Sample_File_4.counts = c(0L, 0L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 403L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Example of the output file:**

```
library(tidyverse)
Combined_inner_join <- list(Sample_File_1, Sample_File_2, Sample_File_3, Sample_File_4) %>% reduce(inner_join, by = "Gene IDs")

dput(head(Combined_inner_join))
structure(list(`Gene IDs` = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000005", 
"ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938"
), Sample_File_1.counts = c(0L, 0L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 242L), Sample_File_2.counts = c(0L, 
0L, 18L, 21L, 3L, 413L), Sample_File_3.counts = c(0L, 0L, 24L, 
13L, 2L, 400L), Sample_File_4.counts = c(0L, 0L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 
403L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you,

Toufiq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a lot simpler than I initially thought it would be. If you first read in all of your files you can assign them to a list using mget to retrieve them from the global environment. Then you can use reduce and inner_join to get your desired file. I think I have the column names they way you want but let me know if there is a different way you want the columns named.

Okay my edit below should do the trick. It is definitely not the most efficient way of doing this but the way that I found to do it. Let me know if it works for you. Depending on how your text files are saved you may need to change the `delim` option in `read_delim` when reading all the files in.

The bonus to this method is that you won't need to call the files from the environment because you can just read them into a list.

```r
library(tidyverse)

file_list <- list()

all_files <- list.files("~/Documents/Research/test_dir", full.names = TRUE)
for(i in 1:length(all_files)) {
  file_list[[i]] <- read_delim(all_files[i], delim = "\t", col_names = FALSE)
}


file_list_named <- list()
col_names <- vector()

for(i in 1:length(all_files)) {

file_list_named[[i]] <- rename(file_list[[i]], gene_ids = X1)

col_names[i] <- unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(all_files[i], split = '.', fixed = TRUE))[1], split = "/", fixed = TRUE))[7] 

colnames(file_list_named[[i]])[2] <- col_names[i]

}

                                                                                                                                                                            
final_df <- file_list_named %>% reduce(inner_join, by = "gene_ids")

write_csv(final_df, "pat_to_file/file.csv", col_names = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you very much for the inputs. Actually none of the text files have column headers (column A (Gene IDs) and column B(.counts) column names). Is it possible to first input column A as "Gene IDs" and column B as " names of the samples for all files in a folder. And then I will run your script.

Comment: So your original text files don’t have headers that you can use and you want to add them in as the file name for the second column?

Comment: yes, that's correct. I want to add Column A as "Gene IDs" and column B as " file name.counts" for all files. Otherwise, I have to add manually in each file and this would be very tedious.

Comment: I think I addressed your issue. I changed the Gene IDs to gene_ids for ease of use with tidyverse functions so be aware of that. The way i'm reading in the files will also read them in alphabetically so be aware of that if it matters.

Comment: thank you very much. I did not notice the edited section.

Answer (score 1):

Try this custom function and see if works,

```
readblk <- function(directory = getwd()) {
  lst <- list.files(directory)
  for (i in 1:length(lst)) {
    tm <- read.csv(lst[i], sep = '\t', header = FALSE)
    colnames(tm) <- c('GeneIDs', paste0('Sample_File_',i,' Counts'))
    if (exists('out') == FALSE) {
      assign('out', tm)
    }
    else{
      out <- merge(out, tm)
    }
  }
  print(out)
}

compiled <-  readblk() 
write.csv(compiled, 'compiled.csv')
```

If the directory where the files are saved is your working directory, there is no need to input anything. Else, add the path for the directory where the files are saved.
I have renamed the headers, as well.